# What waterproof material should I use for vertical facing in water heater closet?

Tags: plumbing

My water heater is in my garage on a platform in its own closet. There was drywall facing about 20" x 26" but I removed it when it got wet from a T&P valve malfunction.

I'd like to replace it with something more water resistant that I can install easily on the wood framing. Maybe something firmer than sheet vinyl.

Answer (score 1):

CBU - "Concrete backer units" - or more commonly cementboard tile base - *e.g.* Durock, Hardibacker, etc. Typically supplied as 3 foot by 5 foot sheets, nominal 1/2" or 1/4" thick.

They all stand up to water exposure well. Some are explicitly treated more for waterproofing, but that won't matter so much in this application as opposed to something like a shower stall that will get wet every day. Here we might expect wet once in 10 years...

Comment: What about water resistant drywall (green color code) USG Sheetrock Brand 5/8 in x 4 ft  x 8 ft. Also in 1/2 in thick if you don't need 5/8" for fire protection.

Comment: Not even close to the same water resistance. I wouldn't consider it remotely suitable.

Comment: OK reading the question again, I see the WH is in a closet so the door is fire resistant and the special fire resistance of the walls is not required, but the OP did mention sheet vinyl which might be combustible so not indicated. If and when there is a tank rupture of a gas fired WH it would be desirable for the entire closet to be water resistant, including the floor, and sealed where the floor meets the walls so that all water goes out into the garage or into a drain. Hence cement board would seem to be reasonable choice. Do any builders use that for these WH closets?